# JDBC Licensing - Packaging jdbc in jar

Tags: java, open-source, licensing, jdbc

I'm packaging my open-source non-commercial java application in a .jar and I'd like to package the JDBC mysql-connector with it as it is a dependency.

The issue that I am having is that I'm uncertain whether or not this is frowned upon or even illegal due to the JDBC license. I've also got the jdbc mysql-connector jar in my code repository.

--

Has anyone been in the same situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your code's license? What version of Connector/J?

Comment: I haven't thought about my code's license as it's a small project so I'm pretty much open to all suggestions and frankly it's not that important to me. I just want to get it right with JDBC and all.

The Connector/J version is 5.1.12

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @matt b's answer and your comment above: given that MySQL Connector/J may be redistributed under the terms of the [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) and you haven't yet chosen a license, one simple expedient would be to license your own code the same [way](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html).

<sup>Fine print: I am not a lawyer.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This email looks a little old but according to http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,36799,36827, mysql-connector-j is licensed under GPL.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding these 20 page long license texts. If the connector is under GPL, does this mean I am not allowed to package the connector inside of my jar?

Comment: @John yes, but you must follow the terms of the GPL. This is a pretty good exploration of what that means: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/public-license-explained

Comment: Thanks Matt. Now that's an explanation I can wrap my head around :-)